# Python regular expressions lookahead

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string : `"aaadaa"` and a substring : `"aa"`. The problem here is that I want to find all the start and end points of the substring in the actual string . The answer should come as a list of tuples for ex :

```
(0, 1)  
(1, 2)
(4, 5)
```

I guess I have to use lookahead assertion but I am not sure how to do the same .

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match an empty group if `aa` matches after that group:

```
In [34]: [m.span() for m in re.finditer('(?=aa)', 'aaadaa')]
Out[34]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (4, 4)]
```

And then just correct the end position (it should be equal to `start + len('aa') - 1`):

```
In [35]: [(m.span()[0], m.span()[1] + 1) for m in re.finditer('(?=aa)', 'aaadaa')]
Out[35]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding lookahead in this case . Can you please explain your answer ? Specially this part of the logic (?=aa) . What exactly does this mean and how does the regex engine process it .

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya, well, this is, actually, a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). `(?=aa)` means "Match an empty group if `aa` matches next". You could rewrite the pattern as `()(?=aa)`, where `()` means "empty group".